# How do I run a dask.distributed cluster in a single thread?

Tags: python, dask

How can I run a complete Dask.distributed cluster in a single thread?  I want to use this for debugging or profiling.

*Note: this is a frequently asked question.  I'm adding the question and answer here to Stack Overflow just for future reuse.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Local Scheduler

If you can get by with the single-machine scheduler's API (just compute) then you can use the single-threaded scheduler

```
x.compute(scheduler='single-threaded')
```

#### Distributed Scheduler - Single Machine

If you want to run a dask.distributed cluster on a single machine you can start the client with no arguments

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()  # Starts local cluster
x.compute()
```

This uses many threads but operates on one machine

#### Distributed Scheduler - Single Process

Alternatively if you want to run everything in a single process then you can use the `processes=False` keyword

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(processes=False)  # Starts local cluster
x.compute()
```

All of the communication and control happen in a single thread, though computation occurs in a separate thread pool.

#### Distributed Scheduler - Single Thread

To run control, communication, and computation all in a single thread you need to create a Tornado concurrent.futures Executor.  Beware, this Tornado API may not be public.

```
from dask.distributed import Scheduler, Worker, Client
from tornado.concurrent import DummyExecutor
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import threading

loop = IOLoop()
e = DummyExecutor()
s = Scheduler(loop=loop)
s.start()
w = Worker(s.address, loop=loop, executor=e)
loop.add_callback(w._start)

async def f():
    async with Client(s.address, start=False) as c:
        future = c.submit(threading.get_ident)
        result = await future
        return result

>>> threading.get_ident() == loop.run_sync(f)
True
```

Comment: Probably an ignorant question but is there any way to do the last `DummyExecutor`-based approach in a synchronous way?

Comment: Not if you want to have only one thread active.  In order for the thread on which you're calling submit, waiting on stuff, etc to be active at the same time as the threads doing work you'll need to engage async programming styles.

Comment: For debugging purposes I have a mock class that implements the main primitives (`submit`, `map`, etc.) and blocks on computation; so submit evaluates the function and returns a future with status `'finished'`, but errors get raised right away. Maybe this is sufficiently different that it doesn't fit into the regular `Client` framework, but it's nice to have full stack traces and to be able to %debug in IPython.