# Understanding Dask scheduler and client

Tags: python, dask

Here's something very basic that I need help understanding:

```
>>> from dask.distributed import Client
>>> import dask.bag as db
>>> c = Client()
>>> dsk = {'x': (lambda x: x + 1, 1), 'y': ['x', 'x'], 'z': (lambda x: db.from_sequence(x).to_dataframe(), 'y')}
>>> c.get(dsk, 'z')
Exception Exception: Exception('Client not running.  Status: None',) in <bound method Future.__del__ of <Future: status: cancelled, key: ('take-155ca6bd6582b78bbeb95ad86fa1d081', 0)>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1764, in get
    results = self.gather(packed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1263, in gather
    direct=direct)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/client.py", line 489, in sync
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 234, in sync
    six.reraise(*error[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 223, in f
    result[0] = yield make_coro()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1156, in _gather
    traceback)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/bag/core.py", line 1160, in to_dataframe
    head = self.take(1)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/bag/core.py", line 1040, in take
    return tuple(b.compute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/base.py", line 97, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/base.py", line 204, in compute
    results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1760, in get
    resources=resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1729, in _graph_to_futures
    'resources': resources})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/client.py", line 584, in _send_to_scheduler
    raise Exception("Client not running.  Status: %s" % self.status)
Exception: Client not running.  Status: None
```

However, if I remove the `to_dataframe()` part, then it runs to completion, I can then call `compute()` on the obtained result.

From looking at Dask examples, it is not clear whether and how one should use Dask datastructures.  Maybe I'm not supposed to use them in task definitions? Or maybe I have to start the scheduler differently?

---

OK, with the help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44193980/5691066 I discovered that if I do:

```
>>> c = Client(processes=False)
```

Then it works the way I'd expect.  I'd still appreciate the explanation though.  Is this because this code will start another Python process which will somehow not "see" the already existing client and use some new instance of that client, which hasn't been started?

Comment: `to_dataframe() ` asks for the described dataframe to be executed and returned as a Pandas dataframe. In Dask, you want to try and avoid asking for the entire dataframe, as you will usually be working with data larger than you can hold. Instead, you want to describe an order of operations that you want Dask to execute for you, and you want to then ask only for some aspect/final result of those operations, which it will then return upon `compute()` being called.

Comment: @kuanb thank you, this is very useful. Would you also happen to know the way to convert from `Bag` to Dask's `Dataframe` without Dask having to compute the Pandas dataframe?

Comment: @kuanb actually, the documentation says: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/bag-creation.html#dask.bag.core.Bag.to_dataframe I can give it a dummy `pandas.DataFrame` to prevent computation. Is this what you mean?

Comment: The be specific, you are calling `db.from_sequence(x).to_dataframe()` *within* a task (it has its own `dsk`!), so that code gets run on a worker that doesn't necessarily know that a Client has been constructed. By default, bag operations run using the multiprocess scheduler, not the distributed one.

Comment: @kuanb I was trying to find a way to construct `dask.DataFrame` in a more straight-forward way, but I didn't know what to pass in constructor arguments. What role does the `dsk` argument play in constructor? Should it always be the top-level graph? Perhaps, `Client.get` is not a good way for starting the schedulers / workers even for a test? What would be the minimal required setup to start just exactly the scheduler I want and the workers I want to have better control of what is going on?

Comment: Tbh I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with that `dsk` dictionary variable. If you just want to see the scheduler run, create a dataframe of some length and then ask for an aspect of it, eg `dask_df.column_a.sum()`.

Comment: @kuanb in the future, I'd like to have something more like AirFlow task definitions. I find that implicitly calling to scheduler is very confusing and hard to debug. So, I'd rather rely on the graph-like definitions

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to construct graphs manually.  You can use dask collections like bag and dataframe normally in your python process and they will send computations to the dask.distributed cluster on their own:

```
>>> from dask.distributed import Client
>>> import dask.bag as db
>>> c = Client()
>>> b = db.from_sequence([1, 2])
>>> df = b.to_dataframe()
>>> df.compute()
```

The dictionaries you're creating are internal data structures.  You don't need to use them.  Using them without deeply understanding how dask works is likely to result in errors.

If you need to write complex task graphs then you should consider using [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) or some of the more advanced real-time functionality of the [dask.distributed concurrent.futures interface](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: My example is very simple, but, eventually, I would need to construct graphs. The reason I'm asking this question is to understand what it does rather than to solve the immediate problem.

Comment: Just to give you a more extended example, where using canned datastructures won't work: suppose I need to fetch data by issuing multiple queries to an external entity, which limits the number of queries per minute I can send. This is a common requirement, that I would like to encapsulate in a component, so that it can be reused with multiple third-party providers. To implement one, I would need to write something on the level of `dask.bag`.

Comment: I've added links to other dask interfaces dask.delayed and concurrent.futures.  They can do everything that custom graphs can do (and more) but are much easier to reason about.

Comment: Well... the link is to the page with the reference to `Client.get`, which is what I was trying to use in my example. Yes, I read the reference before coming here, and that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: It would be so great to have some kind of Dask tutorial for pandas users on big data. I've spent a lot of time compiling information from different sources on how/when to do what in Dask and it could all be avoided if they just had better documentation.